# Javascript translation doesn't work

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, javascript, localisation

I've got problem with **default translation** built in **magento 2**. A made static content deploy, file js-transation.json generated properly but strings didn't translated. 
Site: test-php.pl
Version magento 2.1

Answer (score 0):

### It is a bug at magento2 :).

Does not fixed yet .
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7525

***Hope, magento will come  with a solution in future.***